# Make drop down input Required in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

We have a form developed by a person no longer part of our team. In the form, there is a drop down field that the user can select to categorize an "issue" that is being submitted. When originally developed, we did not require data to be input into this field. We now want to make a selection required before submission. I have effectively no knowledge of angularjs, so I would like some help in how to modify the existing code block to make a selection required. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn-dropdown btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" 
                      data-toggle="dropdown" 
                      aria-expanded="false" 
                      type="button">{{c.data.issueType}} <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li role="presentation" ng-click="c.data.issueType = 'Issue Category A'"><a>Issue Category A</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" ng-click="c.data.issueType = 'Issue Category B'"><a>Issue Category B</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" ng-click="c.data.issueType = 'Issue Category C'"><a>Issue Category C</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd attempt at implementing a select.  A button tag does not support the required attribute.  I think the following is a very simplistic example of what you are wanting:
'

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function() {
  this.data = {
    issueType: 'Issue Category B'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="form-group" ng-controller="myController as c">
    <div>
      <select ng-model="c.data.issueType" required>
        <option value="">Select an Issue Category</option>
        <option value="Issue Category A">Issue Category A</option>
        <option value="Issue Category B">Issue Category B</option>
        <option value="Issue Category C">Issue Category C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <span ng-if="!c.data.issueType">Required</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. I cannot speak to why this section of the form was designed and implemented as pasted in OP. I assume because the presentation of the button fit in with the rest of the form, but have no knowledge as the intake process and the form itself was inherited - YEAH! I will see how I can incorporate your method into the form. Thank you.